# How do I alter this HTML/CSS to make the container expand horizontally to the floated children?

Tags: html, css

This keeps putting the child divs vertically.

### HTML

```
<div class="outer">
    (other stuff here too)

    <div class="containingBox">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="child"></div>
            <div class="child"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.outer
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 700px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.containingBox
{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;

}

.container
{
    position: absolute;
}

.child
{
    position: relative;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ed3qL/

**(I have removed the `overflow-x: hidden` on both `containingBox` and `outer` so you can see the issue.)**

**EDIT:** You can see it works **only until I add a parent outside the parent!!**

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F

This does not: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/1014/

Comment: With `.container {position:absolute;}` you have removed `container` from the document flow. Could you be more clear about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @KevinBoucher I previously did not have it set to absolute, but that also did not work. I want the container to stretch horizontally out to the right so the child divs are all to the right of the previous ones.

Comment: You've got `.containingBox` set to `700px` (same as `.child`) -- there is no room for the `.child` DIVs to flow horizontally.

Comment: @KevinBoucher Normally, the `containingBox` is set to `overflow: hidden` but if a child is too wide, that should still expand to the right. Similar to this: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/seB5F/ But you'll see once I add a parent to the parent, it no longer works: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/1014/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to get it working:

- `.outer` - Removed `position` properties.
- `.containerBox` - Removed class altogether.
- `.container`

  - Removed `position` properties.
  - **Added `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow-x: scroll`.**
- `.child`

  - Removed `position` and `float` properties.
  - **Added `display: inline-block`.**
- Added a `.child:last-child` style that removes the `margin-right: 25px;` from the end.

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G58hh/)***

---

## ***HTML***

```html
<div class="outer">(other stuff here too)
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child">test 111</div>
        <div class="child">test 222</div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="child">test 333</div>
        <div class="child">test 444</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## ***CSS***

```css
.outer {
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 700px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-right: 25px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.child:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the answer. The child divs need to be 700px.

Comment: Your container box is 700px.  How do you expect 2 child containers that are both 700px wide totaling 1400px to fit inside of 700px?

Comment: So what are you wanting exactly? Everything floated left overflowing the container into infinity?

Comment: Yes, exactly like http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F but it seems once you put a parent around that, it doesn't work like that anymore: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/1014/

Comment: That's because you are setting a width on `.par`. Remove it and you'll see the children expand like you want. http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/1015/

Comment: incorrect. Look at the code on the first one. It ALSO has a width set on the parent. It's only when you make a parent's parent that it doesn't work. Please check the code again.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.  I fixed my comment.  See the fiddle in my comment. It works as it should. Add the width back to the `.par` style and you'll have it broke again.

Comment: OK, but I need to set a width on par (for other reasons, par has to be a specific width). So I need another way to do this.

Comment: Why are you using `position: absolute;` on the `.container`? If you have multiple divs with that class, they will overwrite each other and you will only see the last one: http://jsfiddle.net/wngY9/.

Comment: I didn't mention changing. Rather, I'm curious as to why your structure is the way it is. What each level is for.

Comment: The outer level holds this and other content. The containingBox sets the size for this area, the container is what I want to be scrollable (horizontally).

Comment: Please change your answer, this fiddle looks correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your container is a width of 700px, and each child is also a width of 700px... the only way they fit is to put themselves vertically, as two children would take up 1400px which goes beyond the size of the container.  You can either reduce the width on the children, or increase the width of the parent, so multiple children fit in one row.  Float: left only tries to float them to the left IF they fit, otherwise you get them put on separate lines.

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/seB5F/ but once I add a parent to the parent, it no longer does: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/1014/

Comment: This has to do with your use of 'position', your example above doesn't override most of them.  If I also don't override them in your original example then it works the same way: http://jsfiddle.net/Ed3qL/1/  They now appear side by side regardless of the parents size, however, note that they still appear vertical when your window isn't large enough to hold them side by side (the same happens with your above example, too).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/seB5F/1016/ in your above example, I've increased the width of each child.  If you shrink the screen enough you will see the children appear on multiple lines.

Comment: Yes, but you removed the outer parent. That is what causes the problem.

Comment: I clicked the link in your comment. But in this new link you sent, it still has the same problem. they're wrapping.

Comment: As I stated before, they still wrap if your window is not big enough, but they do not wrap as a result of the parent being too small anymore.  Try expanding your window to fit both children side by side.